# CORS golang echo framework

Tags: go, cors, go-echo

I have next Go code:

```
package main

import (
  "database/sql"
  "encoding/json"
  "fmt"
  "net/http"

  _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
  "github.com/labstack/echo"
  "github.com/labstack/echo/middleware"
)

func main() {
  // Echo instance
  e := echo.New()

  // Middleware
  e.Use(middleware.Logger())
  e.Use(middleware.Recover())
  e.Use(middleware.CORS())
  e.POST("/createuser", addUser)
  e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":4000"))
}
```

And Vue js fetch script

```
const res = await fetch('https://localhost:4000/createuser', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(nameAndPhone),
  })
```

Errors in my Firefox console when executing it

```
Extraneous request blocked: Single source policy denies reading remote resource at https://localhost:4000/createuser (Reason: Failed to complete CORS request).
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
```

My Network tab:

```
Blocked OPTIONS localhost:4000 createuser fetch CORS failed          0byte
Blocked POST    localhost:4000 createuser fetch NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI 0byte
```

It works in Postman, but doesn't work from browser because of CORS. Why doesn't it work if I already have `e.Use(middleware.CORS())` in my code?

Comment: This samples could be helpful. [Cookbook](https://echo.labstack.com/cookbook/cors/)

Comment: @Gealber checked it before thanks. I guess I found a reason: don't see 'middleware' dependency in go sum. Looking for solution of how to reinstall it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I was fetching from `https` and not `http`

Fixed js:

```
const res = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/createdebter', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(nameAndPhone),
      })
```

Answer (score 4):

Please follow the next example.

```
e := echo.New()
    e.Use(middleware.CORSWithConfig(middleware.CORSConfig{
      AllowOrigins: []string{"*"},
      AllowHeaders: []string{echo.HeaderOrigin, echo.HeaderContentType, echo.HeaderAccept},
    }))
```

Comment: why is there no AllowMethods:?

Comment: Check the CORSConfig struct

Comment: FYI - if you are still having issues with this example, the cors middleware must be declared before any other middleware.